# XAMPP mysql (Mariadb) has become unreliable

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have used XAMPP for years in Windows without any problems, but lately, it has become unreliable due to mysql (MariaDB). In XAMPP Control Panel mysql sometimes starts alright, sometimes it will crash on startup without any reason - even if it was fine the day before. I have Windows 11. When it crashes like that, I replace the databases and restore mysql (MariaDB) from the backup. It will then work fine for some time, but then after several days, it will crash again. I am copying the error log below - but the strange thing is that even after the error log mysql (MariaDB) in the Control Panel is running fine.

The version I have is: XAMPP Version 8.2.4+ Apache 2.4.56 MariaDB 10.4.28 PHP 8.2.4 (VS16 X86 64bit thread safe) + PEAR phpMyAdmin 5.2.1

Can you please help?

It may well be that the latest version of XAMPP is not as reliable as the previous one. Thanks.

I am copying the mysql error log - but in spite of this error log, mysql was running in the XAMPP Control Panel.

The error log cuts off at the end like this:

`2023-09-12 19:17:18 0 [ERRO`

```
2023-09-12 19:17:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2023-09-12 19:17:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-09-12 19:17:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-09-12 19:17:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-09-12 19:17:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-09-12 19:17:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 681795; transaction id 18382
2023-09-12 19:17:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-09-12 19:17:18 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-09-12 19:17:18 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=9] log sequence number 7200324 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 681804.
2023-09-12 19:17:18 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2023-09-12 19:17:18 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-09-12 19:17:18 0 [ERRO
```

Comment: You already asked this on ServerFault, and even on Unix&Linux, despite the fact this doesn't have anything in common with Unix&Linux. You're already gotten explanation why this is not going to be solved on ServerFault. Take this as an opportunity to rethink your approach to serving and managing apparently important database. That **should not be xampp**. And there **should be backups**, from which you restore in case of severe database corruption like this.

Comment: As you see, not many people are willing to volunteer the exploration of all possible problems that running services this way creates. And, if you want to use xampp ("wamp" is not much better IMO), you're on your own. You've been told this is wrong way to do things, and if you still want to do it, don't ask for help.

Comment: Did you run out of disk space?  As mentioned, https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ is the place to look.  dba.stackexchange.com is a better place for crashes in a database.  See also https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-check/

Comment: This is my answer to Nikita Kipriyanov: I did not ask this question on Server Fault - this was migrated there by moderators. I made a mistake asking on Unix and Linux - I should have paid more attention which forum I as in. For this reason I deleted the question there. I can assure you that I did everything possible to pinpoint this error in XAMPP. The databases were not corrupted as I could use them in WAMP without aby problems.

Comment: This is my answer to Rick James: many thanks for your kind help. I did not run out of space. I would like to ask on dba.stackexchange.com, but I am worried that I'll be criticized again for asking on yet another forum (see what Nikita Kipriyanov wrote).

Comment: Mica, In life you will sometimes be bugged by people with more knowledge than you.  When they want to 'get in your face', let them, but do NOT go hermit on us.  Some people will willingly assist with your questions.  They will beome your friends.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Thank you very much, Wilson. Here are the details of my local setup:

Comment: Thank you very much, Wilson. You are very kind. All my databases are running fine (I have seven of them). I checked each one in XAMPP, phpmyadmin and there is no corruption. So far XAMPP servers are running fine. However, the error log still says that my database may be corrupted. I pasted in on just.it along with STATUS. SHOW ENGINES; says InnodB is enabled. Below are the details of my local setup:
RAM: 16.0 GB
Windows 11 Home
No SSD or NVME devices


Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Server version: 10.4.28-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 8.2.4
https://justpaste.it/dfxd7

Comment: @Mica With the posted information, apparently at some time a Future Date was used and may be contributing to your difficulty.  Good luck with resolving this message.  For improving speed of query completion, view profile, please.

Comment: @Wilson Hauck That's great that you found the discrepancy with the Future Date. Not so great to rectify it as I can see it is a very complicated matter. I'll have to tread very carefully. Many thanks - it is so good to get a clarification on this! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your database may be corrupted in some manner. After you have restored it, try repairing it.

```sql
mysqlcheck [options] [db_name [tbl_name ...]]
```

Comment: I think my case is a bit difficult. In spite of the error log I copied above, the database is running fine. I installed WAMP and copied my WordPress site along with the database to it. Everything was running fine. I would prefer to use XAMPP, but due to its unpredictability I am worried that it will corrupt my database sooner or later again.

Comment: Upgrade, or maybe even downgrade, XAMPP.

Comment: @Mica, Just because the database appears to be running fine does not mean that it is not corrupted.  have you tried to fix it?